# Calling a function with jquery on?

Tags: jquery

I wish to call a method using query and 'on'

How can I do this?

I've tried:

```
$(img).on('mousedown', test());
```

Comment: Difficult to answer without knowning what img is

Comment: @panthro upadte your requirement clearly

Comment: Do you have any further questions after reading the manual at http://api.jquery.com/on/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Remove bracket inside call back function

```
 $(":image").on('mousedown', test);
```

// function define

```
function test(){
    alert("mouse is down");
    }
```

Comment: `$(img).on('mousedown', test);` is the correct, and `function test(){}` to be

Comment: I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: @panthro Can you reproduce your issue on a fiddle..?

Comment: You should probably demonstrate that the function `test()` would be defined elsewhere to make it clearer for the op

Answer (score -1):

This is what you need:

```
$(img).on('mousedown', function(){
test();
});
```

Comment: why overcomplicate things? replace the function definition with `test` and it is syntactically equal.